# Sign script in Linux for SSH access

Tags: security, ssh

I want grant user rights to copy a specific file from a remote server via SSH. And I do not want to give him any opportunity to execute something else on a remote server.

I have an access to a remote machine but I'm not an adimistrator, and I want to give another user possibility to copy specific file but nothing else.

Is there any way to sign a script in linux to avoid modification of this script or something similar that could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution to restrict SSH run only specific command:
http://chihungchan.blogspot.com/2008/08/restrict-ssh-to-run-specific-command.html